# TCP/IP packet loss and correction not working in my code

Tags: c#, c++, tcp

As far as I understood, tcp/ip should correct packets. But it seems like that is not the case in my application. I have a server in C++ and a client in C#. The packet losses happen quite frequently. I send data in c++ as

```
int sentBytes = send(client_, &tempBuffer[0], 1024, 0);
```

and when I print out `sentBytes`, I always get 1024. I receive this in C# as

```
        int numBytes = 0;
        Byte footer = Convert.ToByte('c');
        while (footer != Convert.ToByte('e'))
        {
            int readBytes = 0;

            while (readBytes < 1024)
            {
                int readThisLoop = _stream.Read(_buffer, numBytes, 1024);
                readBytes += readThisLoop;
                if (readThisLoop != 1024)
                {
                    throw new RsuTcpConnectionException("cannot read data");
                    return 0;
                }
            }
            footer = _buffer[numBytes + 1024 - FooterSize];
            numBytes += readBytes - FooterSize;
        }
```

I often don't get full 1024 bytes in the `Read` call. If this is normal, how can I properly read? If I just remove the `if` block, then it tries to read but fails and hangs...

Comment: Use Async mode instead of synchronous.  You will not get all the data in one chunk with TCP.  TCP allows routes and server to split and combine datagrams so there is no guarantee the transmit message will be receive on one chunk.  Also TCP limits size of datagram to 1500 bytes so larger messages will be split.

Comment: TCP is just a byte stream -- there are no packets/messages.

Comment: @G.M. I wouldn't prefer to put it that way, even from a high-level programming perspective. The OS making networking transparent to the programmer does not mean TCP is just a byte stream. [Tcp Protocol Specification](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc793)

Comment: @OguzOzgul By 'byte stream' I was referring specifically to the data transmitted/received.

Comment: Dear OP. it is normal to get less than 1024 bytes when reading from a network stream. The problem here is, if you assert that there MUST BE a total of1024 bytes coming, you should try to continue receiving (with a timeout) and then throw. As @jdweng mentioned, use asynchronous read so that your main thread is not blocked. (If this is in your main thread). The C++ code is insufficient, we don't see what APIs you are using to send.

Answer (score 0):

Asynchronicity is irrelevant to the question. Oguz Ozgul is correct. looping until I get full 1024 bytes solved the issue